# How to get the value in the enumeration declared in the drl file in java

Tags: drools

I started learning drools recently, when I declared an enum type in drl file, but in java, I don't know how to get the value of this enum, can anyone help me?

First: **enums declared in drools file**

```
declare enum OrderStatus
    CREATED(0, "新创建"),
    PAY(1, "已支付"),
    RECEIVED(2, "已接收");

    status: Integer;
    desc: String;
end
```

Second: **I want to get the value of PAY in OrderStatus**

```java
// Get the declared fact type
FactType orderStatusFactType = kieBase.getFactType("rules", "OrderStatus");
```

I don't know how to write it after that, does anyone know?

Comment: I have figured out the solution, which is solved by reflection。

Class<?> factClass = orderStatusFactType.getFactClass();
Method method = factClass.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
Object pay = method.invoke(null, "PAY");

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't do it like that.

If you need it in Java, declare it in Java. You can reference Java enums by importing them as you would any other class.

OrderStatus.java:

```
package com.example;

public enum OrderStatus {
  // ...
}
```

example.drl

```
import com.example.OrderStatus

rule "ExampleRule"
when
  $order: Order( status == null )
then
  modify($order) {
    setStatus( OrderStatus.PAY )
  }
end
```

Since it is already Java, you can import and reference it normally in Java.